# Send Push Notification from iOS using Urban Airship

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I'm able to receive push notifications on an iOS device when sending them from the Urban Airship website, but can't figure out how to send them from the app...

This is the code I use to send notifications from the app:

```
- (void)sendPush {

    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    NSDictionary * push = @{

                            @"audience" : @"all",

                            @"device_types" : @[@"ios"],

                            @"notification" : @{

                                    @"ios": @{

                                    @"alert" : @"ALERT",
                                    @"sound" : @"default",
                                    @"badge" : @"auto",

                                    } 
                            },

                            @"message": @{

                                    @"title": @"TITLE",
                                    @"body": @"BODY",
                                    @"content_type": @"text/html"

                                    }
                            };

    NSData *pushdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:push options:0 error:NULL];

    [request setHTTPBody:pushdata];

    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic]) {

        NSURLCredential *credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:[UAConfig defaultConfig].developmentAppKey password:[UAConfig defaultConfig].developmentAppSecret persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

        [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSHTTPURLResponse * res = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

    NSLog(@"response: %@",res);
    NSLog(@"res %li\n",(long)res.statusCode);

    if (res.statusCode == 202) {

        NSLog(@".success");
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.m . `-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {

    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

} else {

    #if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0

    UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

    }];

    [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = (id)self;    

    #endif
}

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

UAConfig *config = [UAConfig defaultConfig];

[UAirship takeOff:config];

[UAirship push].userPushNotificationsEnabled = YES;
```

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you forgot to start your **NSURLConnection** in `-(void)sendPush.`

```
[[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self] start];
```

Comment: This is what I get in NSLog: `[D] __50-[UAEventManager enqueueUploadOperationWithDelay:]_block_invoke_3 [Line 372] Analytic upload success: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x170228a40> { URL: https://combine.urbanairship.com/warp9/ } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Thu, 12 Jan 2017 19:27:40 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.6.2";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
    "X-UA-Max-Batch" = 500;
    "X-UA-Max-Total" = 5120;
    "X-UA-Max-Wait" = 604800;
    "X-UA-Min-Batch-Interval" = 60;
} }`